# given row value, find the corresponding row index in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   cut_0  cut_1  cut_2  cut_3  waste  picks
0      5      0      0      0      2      1
1      1      2      0      0      2      5
2      1      0      2      0      0      9
3      1      1      0      1      0     10
```

I want to write a general function to match the whole row according to the list. Let's say, I have a `list = [5,0,0,0,2,1]`, so my function should return 0. Because the first row has the exact value like the list `[5,0,0,0,2,1]`.

PS:
I don't want to use such command `df[df['A']==5& df['B']==0]`, since the column name might change in the future. So, I need a general function to apply any type of dataframe.

Comment: What if rows are duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`df.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `axis=1`:

```
l = [5,0,0,0,2,1]

print (df.loc[df.eq(l, 1).all(1)])

   cut_0  cut_1  cut_2  cut_3  waste  picks
0      5      0      0      0      2      1
```

For specific index, you could extend the solution above :

```
df.index[df.eq(l, 1).all(1)][0]
```

Or to retrieve all the index:

```
df.loc[df.eq(l, 1).all(1)].index

#Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: OP wants `index` of match row with list.

Comment: You can use `df.eq(l).all(1).idxmax()`(`df.eq` defaults to axis 1) instead of `df.index[df.eq(l, 1).all(1)][0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the numpy array with the list and check the first row that has everything equal. If you have a RangeIndex there's no need to slice the Index by the argmax, but it's more general to get any label.

```
def first_row_label(l, df):
    m = (df.to_numpy() == l).all(1)
    if m.any():
        return df.index[m.argmax()]
    else:
        return np.NaN

first_row_label([5,0,0,0,2,1], df)
#0

first_row_label([5,5,0,0,2,1], df)
#nan
```